# Transações elásticas com MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, transações

Considerando o seguinte trecho de código:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    using (var conn1 = new SqlConnection(connStrDb1))
    {
        conn1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
        cmd1.CommandText = string.Format("insert into T1 values(1)");
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    using (var conn2 = new SqlConnection(connStrDb2))
    {
        conn2.Open();
        var cmd2 = conn2.CreateCommand();
        cmd2.CommandText = string.Format("insert into T2 values(2)");
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    scope.Complete();
}
```

[*Fonte*](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview#multi-database-applications)

Ao tentar executa-lo localmente em minha aplicação com .NET Framework 4.5, é gerada uma exceção mostrando a necessidade de habilitar o serviço MSTDC.

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider
>   failed on Open. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException: O acesso
>   à rede do Gerenciador de Transações Distribuídas (MSDTC) foi
>   desabilitado. Habilite o acesso à rede do DTC na configuração de
>   segurança do MSDTC usando a ferramenta Administrativa dos Serviços de
>   Componentes.

[Nesse artigo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview) ficou claro para mim que em cenários de aplicativos de plataforma como serviço no Azure por exemplo, o MSDTC não está disponível, e que a capacidade de coordenar transações distribuídas foi integrada ao banco de dados, criando então o conceito de **transações elásticas**. Mas tal recurso só estaria disponível a partir do .NET Framework 4.6.1 ou posterior.

Fiz o upgrade da minha aplicação para o .NET Framework 4.7.2, mas ao tentar executar o mesmo trecho de código **localmente**, ainda tive o mesmo erro.

Relendo o artigo já citado, na seção que fala sobre as limitações, entendi que tal recurso só está disponível caso a aplicação esteja usando o banco de dados do Azure.

> De fato só possível realizar transações distribuídas (utilizando
>   apenas meu servidor MS SQL Server e desconsiderando o cenário do
>   Azure) habilitando o serviço MSTDC? Existe alguma forma de implementar
>   algo como as transações elásticas sem a necessidade do MSTDC?

Estou utilizando o MS SQL Server 2016.